# Edit Android SFGameView layout programmatically

Tags: android, layout, opengl-es

I'd like to insert a pause button and a Highscore text for my game with the pause button at the upper left of the gameview and the highscore text at the upper right. I'd like to code it programmaticaly, but the highscore and button are not showing up. Here's the code :

```
    gameView = new SFGameView(this);

    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams rlp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);

    TextView textBox = new TextView(SFEngine.context);
    textBox.setText("HIGH SCORE");
    textBox.setId(1);
    Button pauseButton = new Button(SFEngine.context);
    pauseButton.setText("PAUSE");
    pauseButton.setGravity(Gravity.RIGHT);

    RelativeLayout layout = new RelativeLayout(this);
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);


    lp.addRule(RelativeLayout.RIGHT_OF, textBox.getId());
    lp.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_TOP);


    layout.addView(textBox);        
    layout.addView(pauseButton,lp);

    layout.addView(gameView,new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

    setContentView(layout,rlp);
```

here's the button listener, the button won't respond to the touch event

```
pauseButton.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener(){
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent e) {
            try{
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            }
            catch(InterruptedException ex){
            }

            return true;
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add the LayoutParams correctly. Each View needs LayoutParams of the type of its parent. E.g. your TextView and Button need RelativeLayout.LayoutParams, and your RelativeLayout needs FrameLayout.LayoutParams (as this is the built-in container for anything you add in setContentView).

For the pauseButton set the RelativeLayout.LayoutParams to WRAP_CONTENT & WRAP_CONTENT, with rules ALIGN_PARENT_TOP & ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT.

For the textBox add another RelativeLayout.LayoutParams with WRAP_CONTENT & WRAP_CONTENT and rules ALIGN_PARENT_TOP & ALIGN_PARENT_LEFT.

Then the RelativeLayout named layout needs FrameLayout.LayoutParams with MATCH_PARENT & MATCH_PARENT.

Example code:

```
    RelativeLayout layout = new RelativeLayout(this);
    layout.setLayoutParams(new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));

    SFGameView game = new SFGameView(this);
    game.setLayoutParams(new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));

    Button btn = new Button(this);
    btn.setText("||");

    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams btnLP = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    btnLP.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_LEFT);
    btnLP.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_TOP);
    btn.setLayoutParams(btnLP);

    TextView tv = new TextView(this);
    tv.setText("Some Text");

    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams textLP = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    textLP.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT);
    textLP.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_TOP);
    tv.setLayoutParams(textLP);

    layout.addView(game);
    layout.addView(btn);
    layout.addView(tv);

    setContentView(layout);
```

As for the listener. Use setOnClickListener (not onTouch).

Comment: i've edited my code and follow your advice but it still won't showed up,the screen only show my game. i set my gameview to align_parent_bottom.

Comment: Add the gameview to the layout before the other two views.

Comment: it showed up but the button seems taken all the space and the highscore text is on the top of it, i tried to set the button.setHeight and set weight still won't work

Comment: Then you mustn't have set the Button's (and possibly the TextView's) LayoutParams to WRAP_CONTENT & WRAP_CONTENT? E.g. new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

Comment: i've set them both to wrap_content

Comment: great,it seems that i missed typing a bit so it doesn't work last time..thanks a lot for the help..

Comment: but it seems the button can't be press even though i've set the listener, i'll put the listener on the code